# Proportional editing on mesh doesn't work

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, proportional-editing

I saw this video on YouTube > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz2ws7CAkgU and was quite interested. From 0:09 till 0:10 you can see that the uploader is moving the verts with proportional editing. I tried this myself but it doesn't work. It doesn't show the proportional editing ring either.

[image]

Can someone help me a little?

Comment: Did you try scroll on your mouse?

Answer (score 4):

Proportional editing works with transform operations like move, rotate and scale. Try clicking G to grab and use mouse wheel to set the influence higher and see if that works.