# Proportional Editing moves whole object

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm trying to follow a video tutorial to learn how to modelling a character in blender. I've reach the point where he explains how to use the Proportional Editing. I'm tryng to do what he says, but this feature is not working in the same way as it works in the tutorial and I don't know why. These are the steps I do :

1. I activate the Proportional Editing by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>
2. I select a vertex
3. I press <kbd>G</kbd>

What I see is not the movements of a lot of vertex together, but of the whole object. Please check the picture attached where you will see that I've tried to move a vertex with the <kbd>G</kbd> and you see what's happened.

[image: picture]

Comment: scroll your mouse down until you see a circle ( make it smaller )

Comment: ohhh I found the error. the circle was too big and I wasn't able to see it. very thanks man.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35577/proportional-editing-on-mesh-doesnt-work

Comment: You can see proportional size of the tool once it's activated (after pressing `O`) in the very bottom of the 3D Viewport (where values of probably any interactive tool are shown). Taking into account that value you can deside whether it's too big or too small

Answer (score 10):

That happens a lot, especially if you've set units for your scene. Simply scroll down with your scroll wheel, and the ring will get smaller and smaller, until you see it in your viewport.

Check to see if the "proportional size" number is decreasing.

[image: Location of proportional size number]

Answer (score 3):

In a version 2.8, when start moving, resizing or rotating a new box will appear in the bottom left corner. If this box is expanded it will show *Proportional Size* value.

The easiest thing to do in this case is **when you start moving** something with the proportional editing, keep pressing <kbd>PageDown</kbd> button until you see the radius of influence, because in your case it is much bigger than the object and even the viewing screen port, so it affects the entire object. The radius can be adjusted with the <kbd>Mouse Scroll Wheel</kbd>, as already pointed above, or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> keyboard buttons.

Comment: Side note: it seems that sometimes you need the proportional size to be less than zero, so even if you scroll wheel down to zero, if you still can't see the circle, keep pressing page down over and over, and eventually the circle will appear.

Comment: Superb, I was stuck and your comment saved my time.