# Proportional Editing Sphere not showing up

Tags: edit-mode, scale

---

I'm trying to use proportional editing on a square with loop cuts. It worked with a different square. Now, I'm left unable to use proportional editing on the new and previous squares. I clicked the loop i wanted to scale and then attempted to use the mouse scroll to set the proportion size, but scrolling doesn't change anything. Is there something i could have changed to cause this?

---

[image: Proportional editing is enabled]

---

[image]

---

This is the previous square I was able to edit.

---

[image]

Comment: Scroll with mouse wheel to adjust proportional editing size, check the 3D view header for the current value

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35577/proportional-editing-on-mesh-doesnt-work. Proprtional editing size is set to 0 on your screenshot.

Comment: Yes. I've used the scroll, nothing happens now. It worked before. The value stays zero. that is my issue.

Comment: Try using PageUp instead of scrolling then. Value should change above 0 if changing it in the proper direction. If you confirm current operation options for the tool will appear in the Last Operator panel where you can try changing them too

Comment: That didn't work for me either, but i opened a new project and it started working again.

Comment: Now its not working in that project.

Answer (score 0):

Proportional editing radius might be too far away, try zooming out your object and see if it appears